# Can not reach Kibana remotely using ELK Docker images

Tags: docker, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a remote Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I downloaded and ran a couple of ELK Docker images, but I seem to be getting the same behavior in all of them. I tried the images in these two repositories: [spujadas/elk-docker](https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker) and [deviantony/docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk). The problem is, in both images, Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana all work perfectly locally, however when I try to reach Kibana from a remote computer using `http://host-ip:5601`, I get a connection timeout and can't reach Kibana. Also, I can reach Elasticsearch from `http://host-ip:9200`. As both the repositories suggest, I injected some data into Logstash, but that didn't work either. Is there some tweak I need to make in order to reach Kibana remotely?

EDIT: I tried opening up port 5601 as suggested [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cannot-access-kibana-remotely/45363/2), but that didn't work either.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a firewall issue, rather than the containers. Are you spinning them all up with `docker-compose` and using the published ports?

Comment: @Rawkode I'm using `docker-compose` and the `docker-compose.yml` files, as provided in both the images, without any changes.

Comment: Change the `docker-compose.yml` port mapping to `- 80:5601` and browse to `http://host-ip` and see if Kibana works. if so, it's firewall.

Comment: @Rawkode I can't do that as I get an error when I change the port to 80 in `docker-compose.yml`, saying the port is already in use. `netstat -l` doesn't list anything with port 80 though, and I'm not running anything else on this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rawkode suggested in the comments, the problem was the firewall. The VM I'm working on was created on Azure and I had to create an inbound security rule to allow Kibana to be accessed from port `5601`. More on this subject can be read from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).